# Toggling DoNotDisturb with code in macOS Big Sur

Tags: notificationcenter, macos-big-sur

In earlier versions of macOS you could toggle DoNotDisturb by modifying the properties file for NotificationCenter. On the Big Sur beta however that's not the case anymore. The new ControlCenter does not seem to write to any property file when you toggle DoNotDisturb, or maybe I just can't find the right file.

Any ideas on how to toggle DoNotDisturb on Big Sur using code?